# Initializing all doubles in a class to zero

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, c++14

I have a struct that only has double member variables, e.g.

```
struct foo { double a, b, c; };
```

Another class has a `std::vector<foo> v` member that calls the `std::vector<foo>::vector(size_t)` constructor in the initializer list.

What I'd like to do is write a default constructor for `foo` so that all the doubles in it are initialized to zero, without having to write

```
foo(): a(0), b(0), c(0) { }
```

I keep needing to add more variables to `foo`, but it doesn't make sense to have them be elements of a container like `std::array<double>`, because they all serve distinct purposes.

Comment: for POD you can use `memset()`

Comment: @Dan, maybe in general context, but I was trying to avoid writing a default-initialized-to-zero wrapper around double.

Comment: @Slava - formally, using `memset` here isn't portable; there's no requirement that all-bits-zero represents a floating-point value of 0.0.

Comment: You know they get initialized to 0 in the vector, right? If yes, then the vector is a red herring. If no, then probably there is no problem to solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've tagged this as C++14, you can initialize member variables like this without having to initialize them in a constructor:

```
struct foo {
    double a = 0.0;
    double b = 0.0;
    double c = 0.0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that this was only allowed for `static const` members.

Comment: @SU3 But note that this may not even be necessary.

Comment: This is actually available since C++11