# Container of struct containing primitive type, zero initialized?

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <vector>
struct S { int x; };
std::vector<S> v;
int main() { v.resize(1000); return v[42].x; }
```

Is the above program guaranteed to return 0 in C++14?  Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing all doubles in a class to zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010793/initializing-all-doubles-in-a-class-to-zero)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because `std::vector::resize` and similar methods perform value initialization by default<sup>†</sup> which in turn value-initializes the members of aggregates:

From [cppr:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> The effects of value initialization are:
>   [...]
>   if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;

and the [Zero Initialiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) part does what we need:

> If T is an non-union class type, all base classes and non-static data members are zero-initialized, and all padding is initialized to zero bits. The constructors, if any, are ignored.

And of course, zero initialization of our member does the right thing:

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.

---

<sup>†</sup>The default allocator does, custom allocators may use different initialization. You can use those to leave such values unitialized, see the full article on [default-insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultInsertable).

Answer (score 3):

> Is the above program guaranteed to return 0 in C++14? Why?

Yes. From [vector.capacity]:

> `void resize(size_type sz);`
>   *13 Effects*: If `sz < size()`, erases the last `size() - sz` elements from the sequence. Otherwise, appends `sz - size()` **default-inserted** elements to the sequence.

Where, from [container.requirements.general]:

> An element of `X` is *default-inserted* if it is initialized by evaluation of the expression `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)` where `p` is the address of the uninitialized storage for the element allocated within `X`.

`construct` for `std::allocator<T>` does, from [default.allocator]:

> ```
> template <class U, class... Args>
> void construct(U* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

So, that's value-initialization. We're doing `new S()`, not `new S`, so the member `x` will be zero-initialized.

---

The ways of *avoiding* this behavior (if desired) are either:

1. Change the allocator. Provide your own allocator type that has two overloads for `construct`: one empty (which would do default-initialization) and one taking `Args&&...`.
2. Change the type. Add a default constructor to `S` that does no initialization.